# How does a complex C style type casting expression work?

Tags: c++, casting

I was looking for a way to uppercase a standard string.  The answer that I found included the following code:

```
int main()
{
    // explicit cast needed to resolve ambiguity
    std::transform(myString.begin(), myString.end(), myString.begin(),
      (int(*)(int)) std::toupper)
}
```

Can someone explain the casting expression “(int(*) (int))”?  All of the other casting examples and descriptions that I’ve found only use simple type casting expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already mentioned, `int (*)(int)` is the type *pointer to a function which takes and returns `int`*. However what is missing here is what this cast expression does: Unlike other cast expressions it does *not* really cast (i.e. it does not convert a value into a different type), but it *selects* from the overloaded set of functions named `std::toupper` the one which has the signature `int(int)`.

Note, however, that this method is somewhat fragile: If for some reason there's no matching function (for example because the corresponding header was not included) but only one non-matching function (so no ambiguity arises), then this cast expression will indeed turn into a cast, more exactly a `reinterpret_cast`, with undesired effects. To make sure that no unintended cast happens, the C++ style cast syntax should be used instead of the C style cast syntax: `static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper)` (actually, in the case of `std::toupper` this case cannot occur because the only alternative function is templated and therefore ambiguous, however it could happen with other overloaded functions).

Coincidentally, the new-style cast syntak is more readable in that case, too.

Another possibility, which works without any cast expression, is the following:

```
int (*ptoupper)(int) = &std::toupper; // here the context provides the required type information
std::transform(myString.begin(), myString.end(), myString.begin(), ptoupper);
```

Note that the reason why the context cannot provide the necessary information is that `std::transform` is templated on the last argument, therefore the compiler cannot determine the correct function to choose.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It's actually a simple typecast - but to a function-pointer type.

`std::toupper` comes in two flavours. One takes `int` and returns `int`; the other takes `int` and `const locale&` and returns `int`. In this case, it's the first one that's wanted, but the compiler wouldn't normally have any way of knowing that.

`(int(*)(int))` is a cast to a function pointer that takes `int` (right-hand portion) and returns `int` (left-hand portion). Only the first version of `toupper` can be cast like that, so it disambiguates for the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, @Chowlett, for the response. If I wanted to use the second flavor, would the proper syntax be `(int(*)(int)(const locale&))` or '(int(*)(int,const locale&))'?

Comment: The latter. Note that you couldn't use it directly in this `transform`, though, since it takes two parameters, and (this version of) `transform` wants a _unary_ function.

Answer (score 3):

(int(*)(int)) is the name of a function pointer **type**. The function returns *(int)*, is a function ***, and takes an *(int)* argument.

Comment: `(int(*)(int))` isn't a function pointer. It's the name of a function pointer **type**. `std::toupper` is the function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int function(int);
```

A function taking `int` and returning `int`.

```
int (*function_pointer)(int);
```

A pointer to a function taking `int` and returning `int`.

```
int (*)(int)
```

The type of a pointer to a function taking `int` and returning `int`.

`std::toupper` from `<cctype>` already has type `int (*)(int)`, but the one in `<locale>` is templatized on `charT`, which I assume is the reason for the cast.  But [`ptr_fun`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ptr_fun.html) would be clearer.